# Extracting JSON values from a SQL Server NVARCHAR column

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to extract the values, but the always return NULL.

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE
(
    JSON_Column NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @TestTable
VALUES
(
    (SELECT 111111 AS idTest1, 222222 AS idTest2 FOR JSON PATH)
);

SELECT 
    JSON_Column,
    JSON_VALUE(JSON_Column,'$.idTest1') AS idTest1,
    JSON_VALUE(JSON_Column,'$.idTest2') AS idTest2

FROM @TestTable
```

Results:

```
[{"idTest1":111111,"idTest2":222222}]   NULL    NULL
```

Expected:

```
[{"idTest1":111111,"idTest2":222222}]   111111  222222
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks to me to be an issue with your JSON not behaving as you expect.

Your JSON is an *array* containing the two values `idTest1` and `idTest2`.  Your path `$.idTest1` doesn't work because the values exist inside the array entry.  Look at the JSON output:

```
[{"idTest1":111111,"idTest2":222222}]  -- The square brackets are a dead giveaway!
```

Due to the array, you need to change your path to factor in the *first* element of it:

```
SELECT JSON_Column,
       JSON_VALUE(JSON_Column,'$[0].idTest1') AS idTest1,
       JSON_VALUE(JSON_Column,'$[0].idTest2') AS idTest2
  FROM @TestTable
```

Note that I have changed the path to `$[0].idTest1`.  This will select the `idTest1` value of the first element in the array.

Incidentally, if you had strict path matching enabled this would have given you an error (as it should) and may have helped you to diagnose the issue more quickly.

A working fiddle is [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=580cd2e06dd4655148b99d07c3183aa7).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER` option on `FOR JSON PATH` clause like this:

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE
(
    JSON_Column NVARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO @TestTable
VALUES
(
    (SELECT 111111 AS idTest1, 222222 AS idTest2 
    FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER )
),
(
    (SELECT 3333 AS idTest1, 44444 AS idTest2 
    FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER )
);

SELECT 
    JSON_Column,
    JSON_VALUE(JSON_Column,'$.idTest1') AS idTest1,
    JSON_VALUE(JSON_Column,'$.idTest2') AS idTest2
FROM @TestTable
```

Result:

```
JSON_Column                          idTest1    idTest2
{"idTest1":111111,"idTest2":222222}  111111      222222
{"idTest1":3333,"idTest2":44444}     3333        44444
```